# Convert Hyper V to EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, hyper-v, amazon-ami, vhd

Hello all I have a bunch of Hyper V images VHD files and need to get them on Amazon Ec2 does anyone know any way to convert these files to AMI or if amazon has a native way of doing this?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Amazon supports importing several virtual machine and disk formats including VHD files.  See http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to move from a VHD to EC2 that I know of BUT, a work around could be to convert the VHD to VMDK (Vmware) then convert VMDK to E2C (conversion from VMDK works)

Or you can just use a VHD or Hyper-V based cloud host like http://www.resellerchoice.com or hostway.com